# Deck of cards wrong output

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm trying to create a deck of cards for a game that I'm making. Why am I getting the wrong results here? The code is supposed to output every card in a deck of 52 cards. I'm new on structures but I think I've done well with this code so far. Yeah, I know there are better ways to do the exact same thing, but I'm a beginner so don't judge me.

```
int main()
{
    struct Card 
    {
        int value;
        char suit;
    };

    Card cards[52]; //Declaring each unique card
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        cards[i].value = i % 13; // 13 values
        if (cards[i].value == 1) {
            cards[i].value = 1;
        }
        if (cards[i].value == 2) {
            cards[i].value = 2;
        }
        if (cards[i].value == 3) {
            cards[i].value = 3;
        }
        if (cards[i].value == 4) {
            cards[i].value = 4;
        }
        if (cards[i].value == 5) {
            cards[i].value = 5;
        }
        if (cards[i].value == 6) {
            cards[i].value = 6;
        }
        if (cards[i].value == 7) {
            cards[i].value = 7;
        }
        if (cards[i].value == 8) {
            cards[i].value = 8;
        }
        if (cards[i].value == 9) {
            cards[i].value = 9;
        }
        if (cards[i].value == 10) {
            cards[i].value = 10;
        }
        if (cards[i].value == 11) {
            cards[i].value = 10;

        }
        if (cards[i].value == 12) {
            cards[i].value = 10;
        }
        if (cards[i].value == 13) {
            cards[i].value = 10;
        }


        cards[i].suit = i / 13;// 4 suits
        if (cards[i].suit == 1) {
            cards[i].suit = 'D';
        }
        if (cards[i].suit == 2) {
            cards[i].suit = 'H';
        }
        if (cards[i].suit == 3) {
            cards[i].suit = 'C';
        }
        if (cards[i].suit == 4) {
            cards[i].suit = 'S';
        }
    }
    for (int count = 0; count < 52; count++) {
        cout << cards[count].value;
        cout << cards[count].suit;
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

```
int main()
{
    struct Card //struct is a way to store many values on 1 array for example
    {
        int value;
        char suit;
    };

    Card cards[52]; //Declaring each unique card
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        cards[i].value = i % 13; // 13 values
        if (cards[i].value == 0) {
            cards[i].value = 1;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 1) {
            cards[i].value = 2;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 2) {
            cards[i].value = 3;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 3) {
            cards[i].value = 4;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 4) {
            cards[i].value = 5;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 5) {
            cards[i].value = 6;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 6) {
            cards[i].value = 7;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 7) {
            cards[i].value = 8;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 8) {
            cards[i].value = 9;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 9) {
            cards[i].value = 10;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 10) {
            cards[i].value = 10;

        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 11) {
            cards[i].value = 10;
        }
        else if (cards[i].value == 12) {
            cards[i].value = 10;
        }


        cards[i].suit = i / 13;// 4 suits
        if (cards[i].suit == 0) {
            cards[i].suit = 'D';
        }
        else if (cards[i].suit == 1) {
            cards[i].suit = 'H';
        }
        else if (cards[i].suit == 2) {
            cards[i].suit = 'C';
        }
        else if (cards[i].suit == 3) {
            cards[i].suit = 'S';
        }
    }
    for (int count = 0; count < 52; count++) {
        cout << cards[count].value;
        cout << cards[count].suit;
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that

```
cards[i].suit = i / 13;
```

is going to produce a value between 0 and 3, not 1 and 4 like your code assumes.

And the same problem exists with

```
cards[i].value = i % 13;
```

which gives a value between 0 and 12, not 1 and 13.

OK, latest problem

```
    if (cards[i].value == 0) {
        cards[i].value = 1;
    }
    if (cards[i].value == 1) {
        cards[i].value = 2;
    }
    if ... etc etc
```

should be

```
    if (cards[i].value == 0) {
        cards[i].value = 1;
    }
    else if (cards[i].value == 1) {
        cards[i].value = 2;
    }
    else if ... etc etc
```

In your version the first if statement (if true) would set the value to 1, but then the next if statement would be true and set the value to 2 and so on. Using `else if` ensures that only one if statement is executed.

Comment: @Pneuma Well the simple way is to write `if (cards[i].suit == 0) {
            cards[i].suit = 'D';
        }` etc. etc.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Wannabe C++ programmers need to learn to start counting at zero as soon as possible. Which to be fair to the poster they are doing in most of the code.

Comment: @john That doesn't mean you can't use `+1` anywhere in your code when it's appropriate to produce the correct results.

Comment: @Pneuma I can't say what's wrong with your latest version unless I can see the latest code. Edit the question and add the latest version of your code.

Comment: @Pneuma Yes, and I've just posted the solution. Does it need more explanation?

Comment: Bam and it works :O. Why is "else if" necessary though? I don't get it.

Comment: You only want one of the if statements to execute, that's what using else if does, as soon as one if statement is true the rest will be skipped. In your version this wasn't true, and it was unfortunate that if one statement set the card value to five (say) then the next if statement tests if the card value is five and sets it to six, and so you get a chain of assignments until the card value reaches 10.

Comment: @Pneuma You should research the `switch` statement, which is a better way to do this kind of thing instead of the massive if statement you have currently.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>    if (cards[i].value == 11) {
>        cards[i].value = 10;
>
>    }
>    if (cards[i].value == 12) {
>        cards[i].value = 10;
>    }
>    if (cards[i].value == 13) {
>        cards[i].value = 10;
>    }
> ```

I believe these are supposed to represent Q, J and K? Might be a typo though.

Also, i / 13 will always round down. This should solve suits:

> ```
>   cards[i].suit = i / 13;// 4 suits
>    if (cards[i].suit == 0) {
>        cards[i].suit = 'D';
>    }
>    if (cards[i].suit == 1) {
>        cards[i].suit = 'H';
>    }
>    if (cards[i].suit == 2) {
>        cards[i].suit = 'C';
>    }
>    if (cards[i].suit == 3) {
>        cards[i].suit = 'S';
>    }
> ```